# VueJS - Use filter or base component to format number

Tags: vue.js, filter, format

I am working on application where i need to format number, currency, date etc. base on user locale.

In VueJS what would you recommend, filters or base component that will be inherited by all components? Please let me know why would you recommend one over other.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understand, filters are a hold over from an earlier version of Vue.js and they're no longer recommended. If you're choosing specifically between filters and using a base component, I guess the base component would be the answer. Though that sounds like overkill for something that could be included as a service/function.

Comment: Thanks for you feedback.How do you use service with VueJS. Sorry for beginner questions.

Comment: For example, you could create your function in a file called `./src/utils/currency.js` and then in your Vue component you could import it like `import currency from './utils/currency';` which would allow you to use in your component methods.